# Can I Perform a Bulk Import to Sharepoint Contacts App?

Tags: import, data, bulk

I am rolling out MS Teams for a small business, and now need to make all our contacts available to all users via Teams. Our client list is maintained in our main business tool, WorkflowMax, from which I can do a basic CSV export without any customisation.

I have tried importing this into a Sharepoint List, and apart from the fact that the import process misclassifies all fields as 'Number' and fails, the lack of any search capability within Lists on the desktop and mobile apps renders it fairly useless.

I have created a Sharepoint Contacts App tab in Teams, and tested 2-way sync with Outlook using some test data, and it looks useable on both platforms. However, I cannot see a way to automate importing data into the Contacts App. Can anyone enlighten me?

Cheers!

I have dug into Power Automate, but while it exposes all my Sharepoint Lists for interaction, it never shows my Contacts App.